# I need to migrate joomla to wordpress

Tags: wordpress, joomla, migration

I could manage to get the FG Joomla to Wordpress but still messy with the migration itself. The thing is that the plugin ask me to erase everything and there are things already migrated, so i planned to make a subdomain and migrate everything there and then finally take that back to the original wordpress.

Is there a way to make it faster? The site has more than 100gb